# Form API: fomatting the date select lists?

Tags: forms, datetime

I'd like to format my date select input, using the following time formats:

- *12-hour format of an hour without leading zeros*
- *Minutes with leading zeros*

Here's my form definition:

```
  $form['scheduled_for'] = array(
    '#type' => 'date_select',
    '#title' => t('Scheduled for'),
    '#date_label_position' => 'within',
    '#date_format' => 'd-F-Y g:i',
    '#date_increment' => 15,
    '#date_year_range' => '-0:+3',
    '#default_value' => time(),
  );
```

However, the hours format as *24-hour format of an hour without leading zeros* (code G).

It's as if 'g' is being turned into 'G'. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [`date_parts_element()`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!date!date_api!date_api_elements.inc/function/date_parts_element/7) there's the line

```
$hours_format  = strpos(strtolower($element['#date_format']), 'a') ? 'g': 'G';
```

This is deciding on whether to be 24 hour on the presence of the AM/PM specifier. If you change the format to `d-F-Y g:i a` it should work I think.

If you don't want to display the AM/PM specifier, but fix it at a particular value, you can do something like this

```
  ...
  // Add a new process function to this date_select to hardcode am/pm.
  $info = element_info('date_select');
  $process = $info['#process'];
  $process[]= 'MYMODULE_date_select_process_am_only';

  $form['scheduled_for'] = array(
    '#type' => 'date_select',
    '#title' => t('Scheduled for'),
    '#date_label_position' => 'within',
    '#date_format' => 'd-F-Y g:i a',
    '#date_increment' => 15,
    '#date_year_range' => '-0:+3',
    '#default_value' => time(),
    '#process' => $process,
  );
  ...

/**
 * #process callback for a date_select element that removes the AM/PM specifier
 * and hardcodes its value to AM.
 */
function MYMODULE_date_select_process_am_only($element) {
  $element['ampm']['#type'] = 'value';
  $element['ampm']['#value'] = 'am';

  return $element;
}
```

It's untested but works in my head (: If you wanted to do the same thing on a number of different forms, there's a more elegant way (let me know if you're interested).

Comment: That does work. It adds an am/pm input box as well, which I wasn't intending to have because in the context of my use case the time will always be during the day time - 3am would never be relevant - but I can live with the extra input box. Thanks.

Comment: @24ma13wg I've added some details for removing the extra input box.